# This man needs help

Tags: cipher

So, I have a cipher challenge, maybe, depending on how difficult I can make this for you guys. Hope you like it.

I need a word, it may even be a sentence; I'm not sure. All I know is that it's somewhere, so I'm giving this to you. I can only provide you with this:

### [image: 8 KB on disk (6,1113 bytes)]

> EnCt2400eb758cb0d3079825471a346850f1b376a25bb400eb758cb0d3079825471a3KjyVUREhcAE
>   xXt1vx1Y542SX1MMrzAybclRTmj1UgMgWJ76QPhJfGf+Qynb0dbgZAJaSIr2wucW+76/UVMJ0KginZ9k
>   j9lT7kc+gkxwb8TQq5O53tEsEIwEmS

If you find this word, it is very important to me, so you must tell me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just findings...

That's a Base64 encoded string, I think, but decoding yields binary.  Magic number is 0x7012DBAD - meaningless.

Comment: Another interesting note is that the "8 KB on disk" is a picture.

Comment: Hmm, and it's a 2535 byte PNG.

Comment: The file definitely looks tampered with.  Likely something hidden inside it.

Comment: if you decode it using javascript's `atob()` method, you just get a random spew of text: `p­Û4y¾ùñÆôw};÷Í¹ã½Zß¼çGõo~úkn[o4y¾ùñÆôw};÷Í¹ã½ZÜ¨òUDDÀÅ{u¿Xç_S¯02mÉQNhõR Xú@øI|gþC)ÛÑÖàdZHöÂçû¾¿QS Ð¨"dÙSîG>LpoÄÐ«¹ÞÑ,`

Answer (score 1):

The letters `EnCt` identify this text as the product of https://encipher.it/

The website uses modern encryption in such a way that our only way to decipher it is to correctly guess the passphrase. Other attacks such as dictionary attacks or brute force will be impractical, unless you chose a very short passphrase (fewer than 8 letters) or used a single dictionary word as the passphrase.

Comment: Nice finding. Perhaps the image showing the 8KB may hide the passphrase?